# iOS - Background uploading of photos

Tags: ios

I want to create an app which will automatically upload new photos in the camera roll to my webservice. Just like the auto-upload functionality of the new Flickr app. Currently i'm investigating how to set this up properly.

The new background functions of iOs 7 can make this happen i guess. But is it for example possible to initiate a Background Transfer Service from a Background Fetch? Or are the fetches disabled if the app isn't opened regularly? In that case, how does Flickr do this?

Comment: I am having the same question. I have read through Apple's documentation on this topic. However, I am still not sure if the best way is to use NSURLSession for the background upload? How can one NSURLSession uploads multiple photos?

Answer (score 0):

You shouhld read the documentation from Apple in regards to [Background Execution and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) - you can also check out [What’s New with Multitasking - Session 204](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) from WWDC 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I am also curious how flickr does that. to answer your question

1. "is it for example possible to initiate a Background Transfer Service from a Background Fetch". YES!
2. "are the fetches disabled if the app isn't opened regularly". I don't know how the scheduler actually works but all the people I met said we should not assume the OS will guarantee to do the fetch even once/day. In practice from the log I can see that flickr fetches at least 1 time/hour.